# How to draw rectangle on canvas in correct position after window resizing?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a webpage which streams user's camera output and detects faces on the video. The canvas and the video seem to resize properly. However, after resizing, the rectangles around detected faces keep being drawn in the same position as before resizing. The code below is for initializing the video and canvas.

```
    let videoX = 0.95*window.innerWidth;
    let videoY = 0.75*videoX;
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { 
    willReadFrequently: true });
```

The code below is for the detection and the drawing of rectangles around faces.

```
   const detectFaces = async () => {
   var prediction = await model.estimateFaces(video, false);

 // Using canvas to draw the video first

 ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

prediction.forEach((predictions) => {

// Drawing rectangle that'll detect the face
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth = "4";
ctx.strokeStyle = "yellow";
ctx.rect(
  predictions.topLeft[0],
  predictions.topLeft[1],
  (predictions.bottomRight[0] - predictions.topLeft[0]),
  (predictions.bottomRight[1] - predictions.topLeft[1])
);
```

I have a resize method to handle window resizing

```
  const resize = () => {
  videoX = 0.95*window.innerWidth;
  videoY = 0.75*videoX;
  canvas.width = videoX;
  canvas.height = videoY;
  video.setAttribute('height', videoX);
  video.setAttribute('width', videoY);
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: 
  true });
  };
```

Please let me know if you have any idea how to solve this!